# Proving a basis and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Hi I'm currently looking at proofs in linear algebra and came across this one and I'm compketely baffled

Suppose $ C_{ij} $ is the $2\times3$ matrix with $1$ in the $ i,j^{th} $ entry and zero everywhere else. Prove
that $ \{C_{11}, C_{12}, C_{13}, C_{21}, C_{22}, C_{23}\} $ is a basis for $ M_{2×3}(R) $ . Also, what is the dimension of
$M_{2×3}(R)?
$

I think this question would follow and isomorphism with $M_{2×3}(R)
$ and $R^{2x3}$
but I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Have you tried taking an arbitrary 2 by 3 matrix and rewriting it as a sum of those matrices you've listed?

Comment: Also, the dimension of $M_{2\times 3}(\mathbb R)$ is the number of the "vectors" that consist a basis.

Comment: @J.DavidTaylor I'm quite new to linear algebra and proofs are something I can't really get my head around.. would you mind explaining a bit

Comment: The dimension of $\Bbb K^n$ is $n$ and the dimension of $\Bbb K^{m\times n}$ is $m\cdot n$. So the dimension of $\Bbb R^{2\times 3}$ is $2\cdot 3=6$. Since there are $6$ matrices in the list you're trying to show is a basis, you need only check that they are linearly independent.

Comment: What is the context? Are you taking a class? Are you reading a book?